# ssh timeout in shell script workaround

Tags: shell, unix, ssh, timeout

I have a script that loops through a list of hosts

```
/usr/local/bin/ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "BatchMode=yes" -n ${host} "/usr/bin/uptime" > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
echo ${host}:FAILED
fi
fi
done
```

The problem is that when it comes across a host that is offline it hangs for some time.

I am running SSH Tectia Server 4.4.12 on i686-pc-linux-gnu
And the ConnectTimeout option is not available.

Any ideas for a workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Does your system have a command named `timeout`? Many do.

Comment: Hi Mark I do not have the timeout command. The lib is there but the command is not the same as on other boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Perform a task for a given length of time by using the `&` operator, backgrounding the process and killing its PID.:

```
/usr/local/bin/ssh -q -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" -o "BatchMode=yes" -n ${host} "/usr/bin/uptime" & PID="$!"

# Allow 5 seconds to elapse before killing the command
sleep 5

kill "$PID"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem here is that now i am testing the return code of the kill vs the return code of the ssh.